# Listing files while working with them - Shell Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a database server that it basic work is to import some specific files, do some calculations and provide data in a web interface.

It's planned for next weeks a hardware replacement, it needs to migrate the database. But there's one problem in it: the actual database is corrupted and show some errors in web interface. This is due to server freezing while importing/calculating, that's why the replacement.

So I'm not willing to just dump the db and restore in the new server. Doesn't make sense to still use the corrupted database and while dumping the old server goes really slow. I have a backup from all files to be imported (the current number is 551) and I'm working on a script to "re-import" all of them and have a nice database again.

The actual server takes ~20 minutes to import each new file. Let's say that new server takes 10 for each file due to its power... It's a long time! And here comes the problem: it receives new file hourly, so there will be more files when it finishes the job.

Restore script start like this:

```
for a in $(ls $BACKUP_DIR | grep part_of_filename); do
```

Question is: does this "ls" will have new file names when they come? File names are timestamp based, so they will be in the end of the list.

Or does this "ls" is execute once and results goes to a temp var?

Thanks.

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is usually a bad idea. Use globbing instead when possible

Comment: Parsing the file names is not the problem itself. Getting new ones to the list it.

Comment: @AlexBueno It's a very big problem if any of the file names contains whitespace or gets expanded as a file pattern.

Comment: @chepner Not the case.

Comment: You are *assuming* that's not the case. It's better to write code that can handle unexpected cases.

Comment: I'm not just assuming... This is NOT the case! I'm the one who create the files to be read, so I'm SURE the files will always have the same names. Is it my system, remember that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`ls` will execute once, at the beginning, and any new files won't show up.

You can rewrite that statement to list the files again at the start of each loop (and, as Trey mentioned, better to use `find`, not `ls`):

```
while all=$(find $BACKUP_DIR/* -type f | grep part_of_filename); do
  for a in $all; do
```

But this has a major problem: it will repeatedly process the same files over and over again.

The script needs to record which files are done. Then it can list the directory again and process any (and only) new files. Here's one way:

```
touch ~/done.list
cd $BACKUP_DIR
# loop while f=first file not in done list:
#   find                       list the files; more portable and safer than ls in pipes and scripts
#   fgrep -v -f ~/done.list    pass through only files not in the done list
#   head -n1                   pass through only the first one
#   grep .                     control the loop (true iff there is something)
while f=`find * -type f | fgrep -v -f ~/done.list | head -n1 | grep .`; do
  <process file $f>
  echo "$f" >> ~/done.list
done
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this one!

Comment: This is the wrong way to iterate over the output of `find`. See [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Also, the output of `find` is unparseable for the same reasons the output of `ls` is.

Comment: harsh. care to back up those assertions with a better answer? ;)

Comment: @webb So far is working pretty fine! I don't have new hardware yet, but old database decided to jam! So I'm doing the restore in another hardware anyway.

Comment: @chepner, while i respect your knowledge and diligence, i contend that sometimes quick-n-dirty is the way to go, e.g., for a time-sensitive task that only has to work on one system once. normally, i would `find | while read` like in the bash faq, but in this case, that would require an extra outer while loop to pick up new files. i think this answer handles spaces and funny characters, but would fail for many thousands of files. if there are many files, better to do something like: `while find . -type f | grep -q -m1 .; do find . -type f | fgrep -v -f ~/done.list | while read f; do ...`

Comment: Quick-and-dirty is something you do *yourself* when you are aware of the risks. It's not something you suggest to people who take the time to ask a question and wait for a response.